# Windows 10 Not Utilizing Update-Sharing for 1511

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have several workstations on a Windows domain set to share Windows 10 updates in hopes that each workstation doesn't have to wastefully download its updates directly from Microsoft:

[image]

This seems to have been working in previous updates, but there doesn't seem to be any share-utilization regarding the Windows 10 1511 update. Each workstation seems to be downloading 1511 independently (directly from Microsoft).

I've heard this update is larger than 4GB, so you can certainly see how extremely wasteful this issues is.

Some of our workstations have this update successfully installed, so I don't understand why the remaining computers aren't downloading the update from these already-updated-computers on the local LAN.

Comment: the 1511 Update is basically a new OS , maybe this only works for normal MSU Updates

Comment: If so, that's disappointing (considering that I decommissioned our WSUS server after upgrading all our workstations to Windows 10 -- due to this update-sharing feature).

Comment: I've never seen this feature work for me... I have the setting enabled too, and I do check where it's getting the updates from... Always seems to come from the internet! :( Is there anything we could be missing?